# Pass data to MapDetailViewController

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotationview

I have annotations on my map. I want to open a new view controller when user taps AccessoryControl and pass data to that view controller.

So I do this:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Details", sender: view)
}
```

then:

```
if segue.identifier == "Details" {

        let placeDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PlaceDetailViewController

        let place: Place = places[?index?]
        placeDetailViewController.place = place
}
```

So I want to get the index of my annotation and don't know how to do this.

Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in ***prepareForSegue***:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue!.identifier == "Details" {
            let vc = segue!.destinationViewController as PlaceDetailViewController
            vc.data = "YOUR_DATA_HERE"
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can make annotation as a property for your **sender** (_view_ for your example) and set it as **vc.annotation = sender.annotation**. Or create any other property